# MVC controller concept

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have `Database` of objects, each object represent file on disk:

This is my object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string browser { get; set; }    
    public string protocol { get; set; }    
    public string family { get; set; }
}
```

In my main page i have button click that lead to page with `DropDownList` with all the files inside sorted by protocol property. 
This is my controller that return collection of object with certain `family` (my object property):

My controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = db.Captures.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToArray();
        list = list.Distinct(new MyObjectByProtocolComparer())
                   .OrderBy(x => x.fileName)
                   .ToArray();            

        ViewBag.Files = list;
        return View();
    }
```

And my Index.cshtml that show my protocols list:

```
<div>

        @Html.DropDownList("File", new SelectList(ViewBag.Files, "Id", "protocol_site"), "Select webmail site", new { style = "vertical-align:middle;" })
        <button type="button">Select</button>
    </div>
```

What i want to add and don't know how is after choose certain protocol file from my `DropDownList` and hit on the button is received list all my files with this specific protocol.
I read [this](http://www.edandersen.com/2013/05/28/asp-net-mvc-basics-part-1-view-model-binding/) article but i am not sure if this is what i want, in the default `MVC` webpage there is the Delete, Create and Details links but i want something different, just add new button, read item name from my `DropDownList` and show my database results over list.
if someone familiar with good tutorial i will be glad to learn, i don't want someone will do my job for me, this is not my style and of course this will not gonna help me understand `MVC` but you need to understand that i am totally new with `Web`and instead of console\winforms this looks like very confusing and unclear (the code with the design and html)

Comment: You have to get the id of the file that was selected from the dropdown; then, you can grab all the files that are related to that id. For example 
public List<FileObject> GetFiles(String File)
{
     List<FileToReturn> _returnFile = new List<FileToReturn>();
   if(File != null)
{
  // you can select the files from the database. Add them to a list and return the list. 
}
return _returnFile ;
}

Comment: What is the "certain protocol file" (in meaning of "protocol")? Is that have any relationship with the question generally (or you just mentioned that exidentally)?

Comment: Can i have an code example or some other example (tutorial etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Button "Select" needs to be wrapped by html *FORM* tag that is in MVC .cshtml view can be rendered by @Html.BeginForm() extension method (see help for it). Once you have an html form, you can make user able to post it back to web server by setting this button as of type "submit". When user pushes it, the browser gathers names and values of html elements which are inside FORM such like *input* or *select* but not *label* etc, turns them into key-value pairs and sends to web server via HTTP POST request to the url specified as FORM's attribute (such like http://myHost.com/Foo/Bar).
Web server receives this request and parses it - both URL query string, headers and, of course, posted data. According to MVC convensions and the default routing, the *http://myHost.com/Foo/Bar* means all request data should be forwarded to the Bar action of the Foo controller. Inside action programemr can access the FORM's values (as well as many other request info) via HttpContext.Request.Form collection. But the another great point of .NET MVC implementation is the model binding mechanism. It tries to map incoming FORMs key-value pairs on Action parameter basing on equality of keys and parameter names (actually, it is even more complicated). Thus, if you had /select name="myDdlId"/ html tag on your page, and user selected 1st option with Id=123, and submitted form, then the incoming FORM key-value pair would be "myDdlId=123". Once you provide your Bar action with *int myDdlId* parameter then binder will automatically populate it with "123" as the key and the parameter names are equal. Not only parameters of simple types can be used in Action - actually, you can create your own MyModel class with MyDdlId integer property - the binder will instantiate the object and set its MyDdlId=123. Default binder is pretty smart and covers most of needs, but you can also create your own binders.
Thus implicit binding greatly helps us not to think of FORMs values collections and key-value pairs, we just provide an Action with the specially designed object as parameter and - voila! - immediately have this object populated with the corresponding values.
Once you have got the selected item's ID and performed query over your db, you have your entities to display for user. You need to have another view model class like MyEntitiesViewModel that can hold entities array. Once you have your very big business entities from database, you create an instance *myEntitiesModel* of MyEntitiesViewModel and populate it with needed entities properties. After that you write *return View("~/Views/AllEntities.cshtml", myEntitiesModel);* that means you're taking *AllEntities.cshtml* template, provide it with myEntitiesModel, render as html page and send back to client.
Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `<div>` with a form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("File", new SelectList(ViewBag.Files, "Id", "protocol_site"), "Select webmail site", new { style = "vertical-align:middle;" })
    <button type="button">Select</button>
</div>
}
```

Implement `POST` request handler in your controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string File)
{
    ...
}
```

Write code to return or redirect to a view with the list of files that match the protocol.

Comment: Can i have another Index method (overload) ?

Comment: Yes. Notice the attribute `[HttpPost]`? So MVC will call this method and pass your drop down list's selected value as `File` when you click the button.

Comment: OK, i have learn something new now, and you told me "Wrap your <div> with a form" - what does it mean ? what this @using (Html.BeginForm.. doing ?

Comment: See *FORM* html tag and its attributes. @HtmlBeginForm is an MVC Razor extension method that renders this tag (actually, you can use pure static html, but this is not good practice here)

Comment: Write your HTML inside that using clause. Html.BeginForm basically renders an HTML form tag. If you want you can write pure HTML instead. Ex: `<form action="/MyController" method="post"><div>...</form>`

Comment: @jim `You can have as much overloads as .NET allows, and the actual one will be choosen automatically basing on routing table design and the actual incoming form values.`  This is not correct.  If you supply two actions with the same name, regardless of their parameters, although the code will compile, you will receive a `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException`.  Decorating actions with different `Http*` attributes will stop them being considered ambiguous, but only because they will then serve a distinct purpose.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО well, now i'm stopping type basics that can be easily googled and MSDNed...

Comment: @JohnH you're probably right - just tried. I thiught, overload is also choosen as mostly matching to the key names. Deleted.

Comment: @user2976270: Are you still confused about Html.BeginForm? Here I have edited my answer.

Comment: What about the rest of the code inside Index.cshtml ? it should be also inside this div ?

Comment: Get familiar with HTML first. think of this `using{}` as a `<form></form>` pair. For the record you can have the rest of your code outside of it.